# Many to Many relationships in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, relationship

I created many to many relationship in Laravel and I want to create store with it. For example I have this code:

```
const INITIAL_PEOPLE = {
    all: [
      {name: "John", city: "NY"}
    ]
}
```

Any people has a tags (many to many relationships). The best way for me would be if my store look like this (unless you have another idea how can I implement and display elements with this relationship):

```
const INITIAL_PEOPLE = {
    all: [
      {name: "John", city: "NY", tags: [id: 1, name: "new_tag"]}
    ]
}
```

This is example like store looks but only data was the server and add by reducers. So how can I create this structure of store (or solve this problem with another way) with reducer?

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the data objects in api-response, before storing them into redux.

You can save the data as follows:

**Assumption:**  There is a unique ID for each person.

```
ReduxStoreState:
{
   "people":{
      "id_1":{
         "id":"id_1",
         "name":"John",
         "city":"NY"
      },
      "id_2":{
         "id":"id_2",
         "name":"Matt",
         "city":"NJ"
      }
   },
   "tagsByPeople":{
      "id_1":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"new_tag"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now you can write `selectors` to fetch Tags by providing `person-ID`